# MongooseJS Save won't call callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using MongooseJS to connect to MongoDB

I am creating a a new Team. Once I save the team, I want to add a reference to the team for my user. But unfortunately, whenever I go to add the team to my user and save the user my callback is not called. Any ideas why?

```
TeamRepository.prototype.createForUser = function(user, data, callback) {
  var team,
    _this = this;
  if (user == null) {
    user = null;
  }
  if (data == null) {
    data = {};
  }
  if (callback == null) {
    callback = (function() {});
  }
  team = new Team({
    name: data.name,
    description: data.description,
    state: data.state
  });
  return this.save(team, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err, team);
    } else {
      user.teams.push({
        team: team._id
      });
      return _this.save(user, function(err) {
        return callback(err, team);
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Specifically this line. Notice I have two nested saves.

```
return _this.save(user, function(err) {
    return callback(err, team);
});
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 5):

I have solved the issue. In my user model, I had hooked into the save event and was not calling next() to move along the save.

```
schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var _this = this;
  if (this.isNew || this.isModified('password')) {
    return hashPassword(this.password, function(err, hash) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      _this.password = hash;
      return next();
    });
  } else {
    return next(); // missing this
  }
});
```

And here is what my TeamRepository.save() looks like since you asked.

```
TeamRepository.prototype.save = function(model, callback) {
  if (model == null) {
    model = null;
  }
  if (callback == null) {
    callback = (function() {});
  }
  if (model) {
    model.increment();
    return model.save(callback);
  } else {
    if (callback) {
      return callback(null);
    }
  }
};
```